# Open subsets of cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

for the past few days I've been studying Analysis and more specific the topology of metric spaces. I was making some exercices on topology since I struggle with the intuïtion behind it. I was trying to answer the following question: Let $(X_1, d_1)$ and $(X_2, d_2)$ be two metric spaces and $X = X_1 \text{ x } X_2$ with the metric
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = d_1(x_1,y_1) + d_2(x_2,y_2)$$
where $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2) \in X$. I already proved that if $A_1$ is an open subset of $X_1$ and $A_2$ is an open subset of $X_2$, then so is $A_1 \text{ x } A_2$ an open subset of $X = X_1 \text{ x } X_2$. However the follow up question is not clear to me. It asks if any subset of $X = X_1 \text{ x } X_2$ can be written in the from $A_1 \text{ x } A_2$, where $A_i$ is an open subset of $X_i$ and $i = 1,2$. I first tried coming up with a counterexample but couldn't find any and proving it had me made use of a inifinite intersection of open subsets which isn't guaranteed to be open :((. Does anyone have any tips concerning this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: *no*. Consider any open ball in $\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$.